# Skeleton Generation algorithm implementation: by niblack

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have been trying to implement the algorithm to find the skeleton of an object proposed by niblack. I require your expertise on that.(paper attached in case more info is required)

So the algorithm states the following steps:

- Calculating the distance transform using the desired metrics (Done.)
- Selecting all pixels which are local maxima in a distance transform (Done.)
- For each local maximum begin a steepest uphill climb from each direct neighbor of equal value that is not a local maximum. Each steepest uphill climb selects, one at a time, a sequence of pixels where the next pixel selected is the climbing neighbor of the previous pixel. (HERE WHERE I AM HAVING PROBLEMS)
- Select all saddle points ( once step 3 is complete, easy to be done)
- For each saddle or 2x2 saddle, begin a steepest uphill climb from the hump ........... (for last step please see paper)

---

Either than my english is failing me or I can't quite comprehend what they mean. So let me try to explain what I understood and you correct me.

so for each pixels there are 4 Direct neighbors. Lets say i located a local maximum that has a maximum intensity of 255, the upper D-neighbor is 220 the right neighbor is 230, the lower D-neighbor is 240 and the left D-neighbor is 220. so my question is how would I indicate this uphill climb ? I mean how would i try to implement this . Can anyone help me with a psuedo code ? knowing that finding a local maximum is already done.

Thank you

paper: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/104996529290026T

Title: Generating Skeletons and Centerlines from the Distance Transform
Author: Niblack, Gibbsons, Capson

Comment: *steepest uphill climb* reads for me as "the biggest difference". Is there anything more to it? Also you linked to a $30 paper; I don't think many of us are going to buy it.

Comment: oops I forgot that I am on my university network. the thing is I thought it might be the biggest difference. So I should find the biggest difference and then set that to true on a mask ? ok I will give that a shot. It was more the way they put it was a bit confusing. Thanks for the help

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz what would be a "run" considered in image processing. like in the following sense: Let R be a run of adjacent neighbors of p all with the maximum value such that the neighbor preceding and the neighbor succeeding the run are smaller valued. 
What in whoever governs the earth's name is that supposed to mean ? I have been trying to implement this condition with no success because I can't even understand it

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz p being a pixel